# Override applicatoinID inside library project's manifest with Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-package-managers

I have a main project which references a library project. They both are compiled with Gradle.

This is the defaultConfig for the main project gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

And this is the defaultConfig for the library project gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

As you can see, I don't declare any applicationId inside the library.

I have a **permission** defined inside my **library** project as below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.library">

<permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

When I build the project, the *applicationId* gets replaced with *com.example.library* (the library package name). And that's not what I want. I want it to be replaced with *com.example.app* since it's my app's *applicationId*.

If I put the **${applicationID}** placeholder inside app's manifest file, everything works.

Does anyone knows if this can be accomplished and how?

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429286/1916449 I think it should just work?

Answer (score 1):

I see the following solution:

**Project build.gradle**

```
ext {
   applicationId = "com.yourproject"
}
```

**App build.gradle**

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId rootProject.applicationId
}
```

**Library build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'ROOT_APPLICATION_ID', rootProject.applicationId
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'ROOT_APPLICATION_ID', "\"" + rootProject.applicationId + ".dev\""
        }
}
```

Also, if you want to use the variable in the Manifest use the following way:

**Library build.gradle**

```
android {

    defaultConfig {        
        manifestPlaceholders = [ROOT_APPLICATION_ID:rootProject.applicationId]
    }

 buildTypes {
            release {
                buildConfigField 'String', 'ROOT_APPLICATION_ID', "\"" + manifestPlaceholders.get("ROOT_APPLICATION_ID")+ "\""
            }
            debug {
               manifestPlaceholders.put("ROOT_APPLICATION_ID", rootProject.applicationId + ".dev");
               buildConfigField 'String', 'ROOT_APPLICATION_ID', "\"" + manifestPlaceholders.get("ROOT_APPLICATION_ID")+ "\""
            }
    }

}
```

The variable from *defaultConfig* will be available in mainfest and variables from *buildTypes* will be available in the code.

**Manifest**

```
<provide android:name="com.lazada.core.storage.db.LazadaContentProvider"
            android:authorities="${ROOT_APPLICATION_ID}.authority"
            android:exported="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how to change values in a manifest 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

In the section *Placeholder support* you will see more details

Comment: Doesn't seem there is a solution in your link. With the manifest merger doc, they only refer to the main app module gradle file. Or at least I didn't see anything about my problem

Answer (score 0):

in your app.gradle

```
    def packagename = "com.packagename";
    android {
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId packagename
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            manifestPlaceholders = [finalApplicationId: packagename + applicationIdSuffix]
        }
        release {
            applicationIdSuffix ""
            manifestPlaceholders = [finalApplicationId: packagename + applicationIdSuffix]
        }
```

In your library's manifest

```
<provider android:name="an.example"
                  android:authorities="${finalApplicationId}.recommendation" />
```

Comment: This kind of works, but fails for tasks like `:lib:processDebugAndroidTestManifest`

Answer (score -4):

Set library applicationId
in library gradle

```
buildTypes {

release { 
applicationId "com.example.library"}}
```

Comment: You mean that if I set the applicationId inside the library, it will get replaced with the main project one? I'll have a try and I'll let you know

Comment: Unfortunately you can't set the applicationId inside a library project. So this is not the right answer, I'm sorry