# Android Facebook ContentProvider and multiple Build Types

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, facebook-android-sdk, sharing

I have setup Facebook sharing with the below, build type specific content provider:

```
<provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderXXX${applicationId} ...
```

applicationId is different per build type, so that I am able to run debug and live builds side by side on one device.

This setup gives me an error on Facebook (image file) sharing:

```
IllegalStateException: A ContentProvider for this app was not set up in the AndroidManifest.xml, please add com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderXXX as a provider to your AndroidManifest.xml file. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android for more info.
```

How can I overcome this problem? How can I get Facebook to take into account my applicationId?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33293868/1565731) is solution you're looking for.

Comment: @Wess Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Manifest code look like below for facebook login and sharing:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/{facebook_app_id}" />
    <!-- To use Facebook Login or Share, also add the FacebookActivity to the manifest:-->
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <!-- If you're sharing links, images or video via the Facebook for Android app, you also need to declare
    the FacebookContentProvider in the manifest. -->
    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider${facebook_app_id}"
        android:exported="true" />
```

**NOTE:**

Your app is currently **live** and available to the public.

Follow below step to make your facebook app live and public:

**1)** Goto https://developers.facebook.com/

**2)** Select your app and goto **App Review** tab.

**3)** Check **YES** for **Your app is currently live and available to the public.** option.

See [I am new How do I make my app live on FB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696738/i-am-new-how-do-i-make-my-app-live-on-fb)

Comment: thanks, worked for me, already spent hours in resolving this issue

Answer (score 1):

Your “applicationId” probably is "com.myname.blabla", and XXX your facebook app id?

I think you should switch to using 2 facebook APP_ID's, and not "applicationId". Put the facebook APP_ID's in your build types and reference them in your manifest. You then don't need to add the "applicationId" from your app.

```
<provider
  android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
  android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider${FACEBOOK_APP_ID}"
  android:exported="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

If your APP_ID is 95xxx3xx60xx73xx, then it should be like:

```
<provider
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider95xxx3xx60xx73xx"
    android:exported="true" />
```

For more information, you can follow [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) link.