# Android: "INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER" error when adding Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, flutter

I am creating multiple white-label apps on Android.

Each of these apps use the same Facebook login.

According to the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

I need to add:

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}"
          android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
          android:exported="true"/>
```

The issue is that we get a conflict error when attempting to use the same app multiple times: `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER` as described here: [Android Facebook content provider authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807789/android-facebook-content-provider-authority)

How can I solve this issue?
Note that I tried to set `android:exported` to `false` but it did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `${APP_ID}` instead of `{APP_ID}`. It works fine for us:

```
<application>
    <provider
        android:name="company.name.utils.SDKInitProvider"
        android:authorities="${APP_ID}.sdk.SDKInitProvider"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

`$applicationId` is defined differently on every product flavour:

```
defaultConfig {
    APP_ID "some.namespace.of"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 29
    ...
}
```

Comment: The Facebook SDK says it has to `android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}"`.
`APP_ID` is referreing the FB ID. Are you saying I can change this to anything i want and the FB SDK would still work?

Comment: Try to add $ before the opening curly bracket. It needs to be a variable: android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider${APP_ID}"

Comment: Check all the providers in the AndroidManifest and make them change dynamically too as much as possible. If you have search provider as in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider#constants then make changes to the authority too