# Flutter Image File share Permission Denial

Tags: flutter, permissions, warnings, share

When i am try to share my directory image via share plug in ! Image is not going to share ! Asking me permission what is that ??? Can any one give me solution on it

```
    FlatButton(
           onPressed: () async {
            Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
            File testFile = new File("${dir.path}/image.png");
            FlutterShareFile.shareImage(dir.path, "image.png", ShareFileType.image);
          },
        )
```

I am getting this type of warning :

E/DatabaseUtils( 8123): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.photogranth.watermark.contentprovider/images/image.png from pid=6574, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
E/DatabaseUtils( 8123):     at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:742)
E/DatabaseUtils( 8123):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:615)
E/DatabaseUtils( 8123):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceFilePermission(ContentProvider.java:606)
E/DatabaseUtils( 8123):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:520)
E/DatabaseUtils( 8123):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:307)
E/DatabaseUtils( 8123):     at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
E/DatabaseUtils( 8123):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)

Answer (score 1):

Did you add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

```
<application>
...
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
</application>
```

Comment: yes i added this code unfourtunetlly error comes again   ===>> * What went wrong:
Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

Exception: The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle could not be built due to the issue above.

Comment: where are you adding this to your XML, this error `'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project` sometimes it means having it in the wrong place. Also, go to your `compileSdkVersion`  in build.gradle `compileSdkVersion to 30` or 29,  instead of 28 if it's 28. Report back please on what happens.

Comment: here is my xml :   </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/AndroidManifest"/>
        </provider>
    </application>

Comment: Look into this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790768/using-applicationid-in-library-manifest and see please